# Problem installing django on a virtual machine with no access to pypi.org

Tags: python, django, pip, virtual-machine

I developed a relatively simple site with Django and I need to deploy it on a Windows VM hosted on a PC on the local network.
These are the requirements:
**requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.5.0
autopep8==1.6.0
Django==4.0.3
Pillow==9.0.1
pycodestyle==2.8.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
toml==0.10.2
tzdata==2022.1
```

Having no access to the internet, I followed these steps:
**PC With Internet**

```
mkdir dependencies
pip download -r requirements.txt -d "./dependencies"
tar cvfz dependencies.tar.gz dependencies
```

I then moved the tar file on the **VM** and did the following:

```
tar zxvf dependencies.tar.gz
cd dependencies
for %x in (dir *.whl) do pip install %x --no-index --force-reinstall
```

The above commands resulted in this **pip freeze**:

```
asgiref @ file:///C:/website/packages/dependencies/asgiref-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Pillow @ file:///C:/website/packages/dependencies/Pillow-9.0.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
pycodestyle @ file:///C:/website/packages/dependencies/pycodestyle-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
sqlparse @ file:///C:/website/packages/dependencies/sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl
toml @ file:///C:/website/packages/dependencies/toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
tzdata @ file:///C:/website/packages/dependencies/tzdata-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

As you can see Django and autopep8 fail to install even though the requirements should be met. What am I missing?

Any help pointing me to the solution would be very much appreciated!!

Thanks

BTW, this is the log:

```
(django_venv) C:\website\packages\dependencies>pip install dir --no-index --force-reinstall
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dir (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dir

(django_venv) C:\website\packages\dependencies>pip install asgiref-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl --no-index --force-reinstall
Processing c:\website\packages\dependencies\asgiref-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: asgiref
  Attempting uninstall: asgiref
    Found existing installation: asgiref 3.5.0
    Uninstalling asgiref-3.5.0:
      Successfully uninstalled asgiref-3.5.0
Successfully installed asgiref-3.5.0

(django_venv) C:\website\packages\dependencies>pip install autopep8-1.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl --no-index --force-reinstall
Processing c:\website\packages\dependencies\autopep8-1.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement toml (from autopep8) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for toml

(django_venv) C:\website\packages\dependencies>pip install Django-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl --no-index --force-reinstall
Processing c:\website\packages\dependencies\django-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tzdata; sys_platform == "win32" (from django) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tzdata; sys_platform == "win32"

(django_venv) C:\website\packages\dependencies>pip install Pillow-9.0.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl --no-index --force-reinstall
Processing c:\website\packages\dependencies\pillow-9.0.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Attempting uninstall: Pillow
    Found existing installation: Pillow 9.0.1
    Uninstalling Pillow-9.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled Pillow-9.0.1
Successfully installed Pillow-9.0.1

(django_venv) C:\website\packages\dependencies>pip install pycodestyle-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl --no-index --force-reinstall
Processing c:\website\packages\dependencies\pycodestyle-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pycodestyle
  Attempting uninstall: pycodestyle
    Found existing installation: pycodestyle 2.8.0
    Uninstalling pycodestyle-2.8.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pycodestyle-2.8.0
Successfully installed pycodestyle-2.8.0

(django_venv) C:\website\packages\dependencies>pip install sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl --no-index --force-reinstall 
Processing c:\website\packages\dependencies\sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: sqlparse
  Attempting uninstall: sqlparse
    Found existing installation: sqlparse 0.4.2
    Uninstalling sqlparse-0.4.2:
      Successfully uninstalled sqlparse-0.4.2
Successfully installed sqlparse-0.4.2

(django_venv) C:\website\packages\dependencies>pip install toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl --no-index --force-reinstall
Processing c:\website\packages\dependencies\toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: toml
  Attempting uninstall: toml
    Found existing installation: toml 0.10.2
    Uninstalling toml-0.10.2:
      Successfully uninstalled toml-0.10.2
Successfully installed toml-0.10.2

(django_venv) C:\website\packages\dependencies>pip install tzdata-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl --no-index --force-reinstall
Processing c:\website\packages\dependencies\tzdata-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: tzdata
  Attempting uninstall: tzdata
    Found existing installation: tzdata 2022.1
    Uninstalling tzdata-2022.1:
      Successfully uninstalled tzdata-2022.1
Successfully installed tzdata-2022.1
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you see in the console when you try to install Django from the tgz file?

Comment: hi @LiorPollak, thanks for the quick reply.
I just added the correct log the question. 
The error for python is:
"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tzdata; sys_platform == "win32" (from Django) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tzdata; sys_platform == "win32"

For autopep I get:
"ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement toml (from autopep8) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for toml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unpacking the archive in the vm, use the [`--find-links` option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-f).

```bash
pip install  -r requirements.txt -f ./dependencies --no-index
```

Comment: I cannot connect to pypi.org on that machine

`(django_venv) C:\website\packages\dependencies>pip install -r requirements.txt -f ./
Looking in links: ./
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref==3.5.0 in c:\website\django_venv\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.5.0)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002463D4C80D0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/autopep8/`

Comment: Try including the --no-index option as well

Comment: That option is already embedded in the command:```for %x in (dir *.whl) do pip install %x --no-index --force-reinstall ```.

Comment: at last I managed to install all the packages with the command you suggested. I guess the first round of the for loop messes with pip as it tries to install 'dir done', I'll run some other test and eventually update the bat script. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

I still don't know the exact reason the command embedded in the for loop fails, but it seems to be the main responsible for the installation problems.

This is the final procedure for setting up the VM locally just by moving the *requirements.txt* and the *dependencies.tar.gz* files inside the same folder.

**VM :**

```
tar zxvf dependencies.tar.gz
pip install  -r requirements.txt -f ./dependencies --no-index
```